# What is the failure rate for PV string blocking diodes?

Tags: diodes, component-failure

PV generators do often contain low voltage bypass diodes at module level, and less frequent high voltage string blocking diodes. Example of such blocking diodes are the Ixys DNA30E2200P (V<sub>RRM</sub> = 2200V) and DSI30-16A (V<sub>RRM</sub> = 1600V).

#### String blocking diodes

These string blocking diodes normally operate in forwarding mode, thus at a higher junction temperature. Let's say forwarding 2,3 Amps at NOCT. NOCT is irradiance 800 W/m², ambient temperature 20ºC, wind 1 m/s.

#### PCB assembly with heat sink

String blocking diodes are often soldered on a PCB and mounted with heat conducting material onto an aluminum heat sink.
[image: enwi-etec_GmbH_GAK_Type_S-800-12DT-X-X-AL-1.0]

#### Failure rate

Can someone point me to authoritative source availble for failure rates of high voltage (V<sub>RRM</sub> > 1500 V) diodes that are used as string blocking diodes in a photovoltaic generator setup, and where the DUT are manufactured 2007 or later?

Comment: Weather related ie hit by lightning... or due to manufacturing defects or due to incorrect installation?

Comment: Usage/weather related. Not manufacturing neither incorrect installation. Those two type of failures are useually caught during new installation commissioning reporting.